# how to copy and paste sql query in pandas read_Sql

Tags: python, sql-server, pandas

I'm new to python and am trying to run sql code in python and have the results in a pandas dataframe. I'm using the following code and the code runs when i have a simple sql query. But when I try to run a super long and complex query with proper formatting in sql, it fails. Can I use any module/option so python recognizes the indention and spacing within sql queries as python specific?

cnxn=...#here it's the connection to my sql server database
sql_2=

```
r'( Select distinct NPI, 
        practice_code=RIGHT('000'+CAST(newcode AS VARCHAR(3)),3),
        SRcode,
        StandardZip,
        Zipclass,
        CountySSA,
        PrimaryCountySSA,
        PrimaryCounty,
        PrimaryCountyClass,
        Lat_Clean,
        Long_Clean
    FROM Docusinporactice a
    LEFT JOIN locationInfo b 
    on a.zip=b.zip
    )
```

sql_data_test=pd.read_sql_query(sql_2, cnxn)

Comment: SQL doesn't care about indentation.

Comment: Can try to wrap long text with triple quotes, like """SOME LONG STRING"""

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `r  = """ Select distinct NPI, 
>           practice_code=RIGHT('000'+CAST(newcode AS VARCHAR(3)),3),
>           SRcode,
>           StandardZip,
>           Zipclass,
>           CountySSA,
>           PrimaryCountySSA,
>           PrimaryCounty,
>           PrimaryCountyClass,
>           Lat_Clean,
>           Long_Clean
>       FROM Docusinporactice a
>       LEFT JOIN locationInfo b 
>       on a.zip=b.zip
>   """`

this way should work the sql statement

Comment: you are welcome. I would appreciate if you'll accept as the answer.